# Relative layout Question

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on relative layout. Basically i would like to put my ticker(lnrTicker) and the footer(txtFooter) at the bottom of the screen.  Everything works file, except the ticker clips off some bottom portion of wvRight element. So i figured out that probably i'll have to put android:layout_above="@id/lnrTicker", in the wvRight component. But whenever i do that, i see compilation error stating that cannot find resource "lnrTicker". How can i achieve the layout, or is there something i'm missing in understanding to layout_above. Here is my layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/wvHeader"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:visibility="gone"       
        android:scrollbars="none"/>     
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/wvLeft"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@id/wvHeader"/>   
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/wvRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"           
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wvLeft"
        android:layout_below="@id/wvHeader"
        android:layout_above="@id/lnrTicker"/>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lnrTicker"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_height="60dp"        
        android:layout_below="@id/wvRight"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/lnrTicker"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to add android:layout_above="@id/lnrTicker", at runtime to wvRight component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add `android:layout_above="@id/lnrTicker"`, at runtime to wvRight component?

Yes.

`<WebView android:layout_above="@+id/lnrTicker"`

then later

`<LinearLayout android:id="@id/lnrTicker"`

The difference is that you're declaring the android:id for the first time in `@id/wvRight` and thus will need the `+`.

Comment: Thank you. That was awesome solution. I never thought the + sign works that way.

Answer (score 0):

simply put the textview on top of the xml, layout_above only works with above declared items.

Comment: and you coudn't use layout_below for a element which had layout above